# Is there is any way to print boolean array as (0,1) in Java(Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, boolean

I want to print boolean array as 0,1 in Java(Android)

Now I print boolean[][] like this

```
Arrays.deepToString(area.paints)
```

Result Sample

> [[true, false, true, false], [true, true, false, false]]

I want print like this

> [[1, 0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 0, 0]]

my boolean[][] is too big to check all values and return 0,1

I need fastest method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just looking to *print* the array, why don't you just utilize `String.replace()`:

```
boolean arr[][] = {{true, false, true, false}, {true, true, false, false}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr).replace("true", "1").replace("false", "0"));
```

This will give you the output

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0]]
```